# ¿Cómo puedo ocultar el nombre de la página que cargo detrás de un #?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Antes solía usar el siguiente script que me cargaba los enlaces ocultando la página detras de un `#`, de modo que la *URL* quedaba de la siguiente forma `www.algunapagina.com/#` en lugar de mostrar `www.algunapagina.com/seccion.html`.

El código era el siguiente:

```
$("#menu a").each(function(){
  var href = $(this).attr("href");
  $(this).attr({ href: "#"});
  $(this).click(function(){ 
    $("#section").load(href);  
  });
});
```

Ahora estoy intentando hacer lo mismo, pero no con un `a` sino con un `button`, y como ya no cargo la página dentro de un `div` sino en la propia pestaña, estoy usando `window.open` de la siguiente forma...

```
var href = "/paginadestino.html";
$(this).attr({ href: "#"});
window.open(href, "_self")
```

El problema es que la página se abre, pero sigue mostrando `paginadestino.html` en la *URL* en vez de ocultarla detras del `#`.

Comment: No se puede hacer lo que quieres (ocultar la URL de una nueva página que estás cargando). Por otro lado... ¿Por qué quieres hacer eso? Generalmente se intenta lo contrario, que las URL definan el estado actual para que puedas ir directamente a donde te interesa

Answer (score 0):

aquí tienes un problema porque el ejemplo que das al principio tiene una naturaleza completamente diferente de lo que quieres hacer, porque cuando haces un $(elemento).load(href) esta cargando parcialmente una código dentro de tu elemento, pero en el otro caso estas redireccionando a otra pagina y uno de los requisitos es de que este puesto el url en la pagina.

posible solución
    ejemplo

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var href = $("#aEjemplo").attr("href");
    $("#aEjemplo").attr({ href: "#"});
    $("#aEjemplo").click(function(){ 
        window.location.href = href;
    });
</script>
```

mandar un parametro como yo hice deleteUrl
y poner en la otro pagina que estas redireccionando un codigo como este

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
    if(urlParams.has('deleteUrl') && urlParams.get('deleteUrl') === "true"){
        //el codigo aqui para remplazar del url lo que quieres
    }
</script>
```

esto es lo que se me ocurre en primera instancia, esta un poco atipico esto pero espero que te sirva de algo mi idea, saludos

Answer (score 0):

No es posible ocultar la *URL*. El método `load` de *jQuery* da una posible solución a esto. Lo que hace es poner toda la información descargada de la *URL* nueva en un `div` o alguna otra etiqueta *HTML*.

En el siguiente ejemplo se puede ver que la *URL* no cambia, pero sí el contenido de la página. En este caso es `https://stacksnippets.net/js`, y descarga la nueva *URL*, que es `https://stacksnippets.net`, y muestra el contenido en `div` de `id = "section"`.

Para mostrar la *URL* actual hago `location.href`.

Para agregar el `#` en la página principal, la página principal debería cargar el código *jQuery* y las demás funciones que cambian a la página que necesites con `load`.

Código:

```js
console.log(location.href)
var a = ()=>(
  $("#section").load("https://stacksnippets.net"),
  console.log(location.href)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Al clickear el botón, se mostrará el contenido de otra página justo debajo.
<div>
  <button onclick="a()">Cambiar página</button>
</div>
<div id="section"></div>
```